# second(verb) VS support(verb)

Tags: word-difference

[support:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/support_1)

> to approve of an idea or of a person or organization and help them to be successful

[second:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/second_4)

> to officially support a proposal made by another person in a meeting

They are like and both can mean "be behind someone".

---

In StackExchange, I often see someone will comment like *I second you/your ...* to show their agreements to the answer above.

- To the case above, can *second* be replaced by *support*?
- What difference between them?
- When should I prefer one over another?

Comment: "second" usually refers to approval in voting situations, though it can be used informally for "agreement".

Comment: @user3169 Valuable information! Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example about StackExchange, second can be replaced with support

Generally, second is more formal and support has a more broad meaning. Support can also be used for describing physical situations

> "The beam supports the building, so it doesn't collapse"
>
> "I will support your running for president"

Second is used while speaking formally, think business meetings and trials

> "I second the motion"